# post one form field using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery's ajaxForm [plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) to upload an image, i have multiple fields in my form with some kind of form validation.
When i post the form , it prompts validation alerts of other fields,
it means it is posting all the fields,
So, my question is, can we post only one field using jquery?
If yes, then where am i wrong, or what can be another solution?
I tried

```
$("#my_form :file").ajaxForm({});
```

It did'nt worked, promts occurs !

Comment: How about we get the rest of the pertinent code?

Comment: $.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } ); see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
// prepare Options Object 
var options = { 
    data: { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }
}; 

// pass options to ajaxForm 
$("#my_form :file").ajaxForm(options);
```

Read [option-object](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object)